# Reports no working for lots of records

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a Main Report and two sub reports within the the main report in SSRS. When I have report to be working wit 100 records the report keeps on loading but never show up. When I have just 4 records it works with some time.

How do I display the report to generate faster for lots of records.

Comment: The reports are working faster individually, but when I include the sub reports into the main report then the report does not load and keeps on showin the messge Loading.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one (or both) of your subreports need too much performance. When you just have 4 records the sub reports are executed 4 times. If yo do have 100 then reports are executed 100 times, so naturally it takes longer.

Try increasing the performance for the subreport so the loading gets faster.

To increase performance first check the Execution Log to see why the report is slow and then try to fix it. There could be various reasons as why your report is not as fast as it could be so you'll have to find out for yourself using the links i provide.

[Check Execution Log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159110(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Increase Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Even for the 4 pages to be displayed it is taking a longer time to generate the report. How can I improve the performance of the report?

Comment: i've updated my answer, i hope it helps you finding out how to make your report faster.